# Firestore Realtime updates to Material UI Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui

So my current code is below, I am trying to update a material ui table in realtime with information from the firestore database. I'm able to read information from the database and insert it into an array but when I set the table data to equal the array, it doesnt change anything. I have read that I should be using states to do this, but I am fairly new to React/JS and am not really sure on how to implement this in my current situation. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**EDITED**

I implemented the response from @Mateen but the code compiles successfully but on the app itself, the following error pops up.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

**Firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {******};


export const myFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const baseDb = myFirebase.firestore();
export const db = baseDb;

let ref = db.collection('AQ-gear-distribution');
let peopleref = db.collection('users');

var tempname;
var tempclass;
var tempitem;
var tempdate;
var tempentry;

var tableInfo;

function createData(name, classs, item, date) {
  return { name, classs, item, date };
}

let ref = db.collection('AQ-gear-distribution');
let peopleref = db.collection('users');

var tempname;
var tempclass;
var tempitem;
var tempdate;
var tempentry;

function createData(name, classs, item, date) {
  return { name, classs, item, date };
}

export function Populate() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const data2 = [];
    ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        tempname = doc.data().user;
        tempitem = doc.data().item;
        tempdate = doc.data().date;
        peopleref.where('username', '==', tempname).get().then(function(querySnapshot){
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc2) {
            if(doc2.empty)
            {
              tempclass = "Unknown";
            } else {
              tempclass = doc2.data().class;
            }
          });
          tempname = doc.data().user;
          tempitem = doc.data().item;
          tempdate = doc.data().date;
          tempentry = createData(tempname, tempclass, tempitem, tempdate);
          console.log(data2);
          data2.push(tempentry);
        });
      });
    });
    setData(data2)
  }, [])
  return (data)
}
```

**DenseTable.js**

```
//This is the core of my table file

const rows = Populate();



export default function EnhancedTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState('asc');
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState('classs');
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);

  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === 'asc';
    setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
      setSelected(newSelecteds);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };

  const handleClick = (event, name) => {
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(name);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }

    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const isSelected = (name) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={'medium'}
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <StyledTableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.name}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <StyledTableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox
                          checked={isItemSelected}
                          inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                        />
                      </StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none">
                        {row.name}
                      </StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.classs}</StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.item}</StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.date}</StyledTableCell>
                    </StyledTableRow>
                  );
                })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Didn't you get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You want show the updated table data when it's set to the data you fetched from firebase. In *React* to re-renders a component you need to update the props/state, others being force update. In case of you, maintains a state, (by `useState` if you're using `function component`), and update that state when your data is ready and react will render the component.

A psuedo demo:

```js
const myTable = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
      // fetch your data here
      // when data is ready setData(<fetched data>)}, 
    [])
    return (<TableCell>{data}<TableCell>)
}
```

Now, if `data` is updated by invoking `setData`, `myTable` will rerender.

---

Updated:

In `const rows = Populate();` you're calling a function component? It's highly recommended to *render*(`<Populate />`) component instead of calling them directly. Calling `Function Component` directly produces bugs and errors.
The Reason was explained here, [Don't call a React function component](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component)

Comment: Thanks @Mateen I have edited my original post to include changes that you suggested. I don't know if I implemented it correctly because I am getting an error on the app itself when I open it in my web browser.

Comment: It's hard for me to debug the code line by line. Can you explicitly mention in which lines you made changes?

Comment: In the Firebase.js file at the bottom i tried to implement  the demo that you shared. Then in the DenseTable.js file, I use it to return an array to the table

Comment: Well, I point a problem in your code and edited my answer, see if it may help you.